# How to setInterval for times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create javascript time using particular timezone it works good but looping not working please solve.

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script language="JavaScript">

var myVar = setInterval(calcTime('Kolkata', '+5.5'), 1000);
function calcTime(city, offset) {

   d = new Date();
   utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);    
   nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));    
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nd.toLocaleString();

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `calcTime('Kolkata', '+5.5')` this will call the function. try `calcTime.bibd(this, 'Kolkata', '+5.5')`

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` takes function reference not function returned value

```
setInterval(function(){
  calcTime('Kolkata', '+5.5');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){calcTime('Kolkata', '+5.5')}, 1000);
function calcTime(city, offset) {

   d = new Date();
   utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);    
   nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));    
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nd.toLocaleString();

}
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xcwvme2h/